# QR code restaurant menu user authorization

Tags: authentication, authorization, qr-code

We are creating QR code restaurant menu for ordering meals and drinks in our local restaurant. Everything went smooth until we reached a problem.

Since QR codes are just simply URLs that you are redirected to, how can you authorise only restaurant users to use your app and order a meal / drink? Otherwise, someone from outside knowing the table URL, can cause confusion and wasted time by placing an order while not actually being in the restaurant.

Is there any common pattern to follow? We were thinking about some tokenisation - first user who scans the QR code of the table, can share his (newly created QR code) with his friends around the table, only if the waiter / waitress approves their order (visually checks that someone is really sitting on that table).

Answer (score 0):

The most user-friendly solution I can think of, is to handle payments during the ordering process. This reduces your workload on employees and ensures legitimate usage.

I've seen it at many local restaurants with QR ordering. And, in the few cases someone can't pay online, your employees can take cash like usual. It should overall accelerate your workflow and solves the issue.